# Cannot get items in the same line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `bootstrap v.3` and I'm trying to get the item in the same line using `form-horizontal` class, however I'm not able to get this work, see the code below:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div class="grid one-half">
     <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <img id="footer-logo" src="#" alt="">
       <div id="copyright">
     <p>All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </div><!--/#copyright-->
                <div id="credit">
                   <p>Powered by <a href="http://wordpress.org" rel="nofollow">WordPress</a>.</p>
                </div><!--/#credit-->
      </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: The form classes should only be used on forms.

Comment: Also "grid" and "one-half" are not standard bootstrap classes.  Is this Genesis framework?  You ought to reference the docs here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: @skribe yep is genesis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/wne5qq5q/2/) what you are looking for?

```
<form class="form-inline">

  <div class="form-group">
      <img id="footer-logo" src="http://innovativeprofessionaloffices.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/seo-for-small-business.jpg" alt="">
   </div>

  <div class="form-group">
     <div id="copyright">
                    <p>All Rights Reserved.</p>
     </div><!--/#copyright-->
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
     <div id="credit">
        <p>Powered by <a href="http://wordpress.org" rel="nofollow">WordPress</a>.</p>
  </div><!--/#credit-->
 </div>
</form>
```

Ref:[Forms Bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.asp)

Comment: If you consider this answer useful, please upvote it as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
.form-group{
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use style="display:inline-block;"

```
<div class="grid one-half">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group" >
            <img id="footer-logo" src="#" alt="" style="display:inline-block;">
            <div id="copyright"  style="display:inline-block;">
                <p>All Rights Reserved.</p>
            </div><!--/#copyright-->
            <div id="credit"  style="display:inline-block;">
               <p>Powered by <a href="http://wordpress.org" rel="nofollow">WordPress</a>.</p>
            </div><!--/#credit-->
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Maybe this would work, but it is still bad advice.  Bootstrap has a "col-*" classes in their responsive grid system for a reason.